# code 610 returned during geocoding call- Android Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Whenever I tries to search a location using geoCoding, it always returns error code 610. I searched for this code and the developer site gives the following reason: **The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given.**Can anyone help me understand

1. what is meant by **"does not match the domain for which it was given."**
2. Does it depend upon the key with which app is signed.? Because right now, I am using map key which was not generated with the key with which app is signed.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide more details. Code or API you are using.

Comment: Seeing as you also need to insert your package name after your SHA key: yes, it depends which app it's for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because right now, I am using map key which was not generated with the key with which app is signed.

That is your problem, the API key must be registered for the certificate that the application is signed with - you can register debug certificates, but must switch to a release certificate before releasing on Google Play.

During the registration, you must also supply the package of your application (defined in your manifest file), which is the domain that must match.